# Only select initiate childs of parent using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I think that is a very simple problem, but I don't seem to get it right.
I want to style a list using css, but I ably want to effect the "top level < li > elements.

[See my problem live](http://jsfiddle.net/4PPqd/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="test">
<li>1</li>
<li>2
    <ul>
        <li>2.1 - should not be red</li>
        <li>2.2 - should not be red</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>3</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.test > li {
     color: #f00;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you don't have a rule set for the embedded list items

Comment: You haven't closed your <ul> element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. You didn't set the `color` of the other `li`s so it's inheriting from the parent.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/L844L/)

```
.test > li {
    color: #f00;
}
li {
    color: #0f0;
}
```